# Google sheet script to copy a value indipendently from the source cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a google sheet script function that copy in my cell the result of a formula in another cell.
I need the cell to get the first result and then become independent from the other cell because the formula result can become N/D but I need the second cell to keep the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the output of the formula in another given cell:
Here an example:

```
/**
* The column B hosts the formulas and the column A hosts the output
*/
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(ss.getRange("B1").getValue());
}
```

### Edit:

To copy a range use `.setValues()` and `.getValues()` functions:

```
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A1:A").setValues(ss.getRange("B1:B").getValues());
}
```

### References:

[getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
[setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
[getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
[setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the script. Can you adjust it to copy the entire column B in A; I tried alone putting A1:A1000 instead of A1 and same with B1 but it copies only the first one in the whole column.

Comment: Edited the question to address your comment.

Comment: Perfect, I'm solved my problems after 5 days. You really helped me a lot.